# Operator '==' cant be applied to 'Boolean' and 'Char'

Tags: kotlin, char, boolean, operators

So i want to compare three members of an array with as little code as possible. Heres what i did:

```
for(i in 0..2) {
    if(board[i][0] == board[i][1] == board[i][2]) {
        return true
    } else if(board[0][i] == board[1][i] == board[2][i]) {
        return true
    }
}
```

(All of the values ar Char's FYI) But it didnt work. I get this error message "Operator '==' cant be applied to 'Boolean' and 'Char'". I also tried using .equals, but that just didnt work. Any ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a small function to keep it more readable and tidy, especially if You need to do that comparison often:

```
fun allEqual(vararg items: Any) : Boolean {
    for(i in 1..(items.size-1)){
        if(items[0] != items[i]) return false
    }
    return true
}
```

And invoke simply by comma separating values:

```
allEqual(board[i][0], board[i][1], board[i][2])
```

Comment: Good and clean solution.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know Kotlin specifically, but most* languages don't allow you to compare 3 values at the same time. What your error message is communicating is that your code ends up comparing

"Is board[i][0] equal to board[i][1]?" which is true/false (Boolean)

to

board[i][2], which is a Char.

*I don't know of any, but maybe there's one out there that does.

Comment: Python, according to https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

Comment: I'm only seeing binary comparisons in that reference

Comment: "Formally, if a, b, c, …, y, z are expressions and op1, op2, …, opN are comparison operators, then a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z is equivalent to a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z, except that each expression is evaluated at most once." And `==` is listed as a comparison operator.

Answer (score 0):

You have included this condition:

```
if(board[i][0] == board[i][1] == board[i][2])
```

Firstly, this one is compared: `board[i][1] == board[i][2]`

After comparing, it returns `true`. After that if logic converts to:

```
if(board[i][0] == true)
```

Now, `board[i][0]` is a `char` and you are trying to compare it to a boolean which is not possible. That's why you are getting this error.

You have to change the logic to:

```
if((board[i][0] == board[i][1]) && (board[i][1] == board[i][2]))
```

So, your code will be:

```
for(i in 0..2) {
    if((board[i][0] == board[i][1]) && (board[i][1] == board[i][2])) {
        return true
    } else if((board[0][i] == board[1][i]) && (board[1][i] == board[2][i])) {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to note that "firstly, this one is compared..." is not exactly accurate, as this would be a compile time error. So the compiler would infer that the first comparison would yield a `Boolean` type value, which it then sees to be compared to a `Char`, hence the error. Your solution is correct though.

Comment: @jingx I think you misunderstand me. I have explained that at the time of compiling it will execute in that way.

Comment: At compile time there is no such thing as "after comparing, it returns true".

Comment: Very late but you once again misunderstood Avijit's statement. They mention nothing about the compiler compiling the statement to a true. They are talking about "order". The compiler will generate bytecode, and this bytecode will first compare the last two equality operators and then compare the first against the result. The "if(board[i][0] == true)" Is not actually representing code it was purely for the sake of explaining the logic. The last two are computed first, then that result is compared against the first, at run time. They simply represented it as code for ease of understanding...

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
for (i in 0..2) {
    if (board[i].toSet().size == 1)
        return true
    else if (board.map { it[i] }.toSet().size == 1)
        return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, your first comparison returns Boolean, and the second compares Boolean to Char.

You can use an extension function, and transitivity to simplify things:

```
fun Any.equalsAll(vararg others: Any):Boolean
{
    others.forEach {
        if(it!=this)
            return false
    }
    return true
}
```

and call:

```
 if (board[0][i].equalsAll(board[1][i], board[2][i]))
```